# Broadcasting 1s of a 2D matrix to a 1-hot 3D matrix

Tags: matrix, julia, array-broadcasting

Given the 2D matrix `A`, how can I broadcast it to create 3D matrix `B`?

```
A = [[1 1 1 1 0];[0 0 0 0 1]]
B = cat([[1 0 0 0 0];[0 0 0 0 0]],
        [[0 1 0 0 0];[0 0 0 0 0]], 
        [[0 0 1 0 0];[0 0 0 0 0]], 
        [[0 0 0 1 0];[0 0 0 0 0]], 
        [[0 0 0 0 0];[0 0 0 0 1]], dims=3)
```

I've tagged `numpy-broadcasting` for this question because while I'm using Julia 1.2.0, Julia broadcasting is modelled on NumPy broadcasting, so there may be a similar shared solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if this will meet your definition of "broadcasting", but a natural way to get what you want would be:

```
julia> cat(diagm.(getindex.(Ref(A), 1:2, :))..., dims=3)
5×5×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  0  0  0  0
 0  1  0  0  0
 0  0  1  0  0
 0  0  0  1  0
 0  0  0  0  0

[:, :, 2] =
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  1
```

or if you would actually prefer to avoid broadcasting (which seems simpler in this case):

```
julia> cat((diagm(A[i, :]) for i in 1:2)..., dims=3)
5×5×2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  0  0  0  0
 0  1  0  0  0
 0  0  1  0  0
 0  0  0  1  0
 0  0  0  0  0

[:, :, 2] =
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  0
 0  0  0  0  1
```

#### EDIT

Given your comment the easiest way to get exactly what you wanted is to use a comprehension:

```
[j==k ? A[i,j] : 0 for i in axes(A, 1), j in axes(A, 2), k in axes(A, 2)]
```

this is the same using broadcasting, but it is rather ugly:

```
((i,j,k) -> j==k ? A[i,j] : 0).(axes(A, 1), reshape(axes(A, 2), 1, :), reshape(axes(A, 2), 1, 1, :))
```

or

```
((i,j,k) -> j==k * A[i,j]).(axes(A, 1), reshape(axes(A, 2), 1, :), reshape(axes(A, 2), 1, 1, :))
```

Comment: Thanks very much for this! However, the 3D matrix you're constructing isn't quite what I'm looking for. I'm trying to create a `2×5×5 Array{Int64,3}`. I'm playing in Julia now to see if I can still use your answer's logic. Although I think the resulting matrix `B` that I'm trying to construct isn't possible to create via `diagm`.

Comment: Ah - right. Sorry for not noticing that. I will update an answer.

Comment: the simplest fix is `permutedims(cat((diagm(A[i, :]) for i in 1:2)..., dims=3), [3,2,1])` but probably it can be improved.

Comment: Thank you!! That does exactly what I need.

Comment: I have updated an answer with a comprehension that I think gets you what you want in one shot (also it should be more efficient as it allocates less).

Comment: Thank you very much! This was causing me such a big headache ..

Comment: I used `axes` to get a generality of the in case the dimensions of your input array changed.